# Python google sheets cells populate evry second

Tags: python, gspread

Im trying to populate each cell from colum A for example once a second, with this code i got one cell updating each second, how can i make the update in a row?
I tryed wks update cells but i dont know how it works, im not a programmer

```
import nsrt_mk3_dev
import gspread
import time
nsrt = nsrt_mk3_dev.NsrtMk3Dev('COM11')
model = nsrt.read_model()
sa = gspread.service_account()
sh = sa.open("DevSchiu")
wks = sh.worksheet("Folha1")



while(1):

    leq_level = nsrt.read_leq()
    weighting = nsrt.read_weighting()
    weighted_level = nsrt.read_level()

    wks.update('a2', leq_level )
    print(f'DecibelLevel: {leq_level:0.2f} dB, {weighting} value: {weighted_level:0.2f}')
    time.sleep(1)
```